# How to prevent .Net SOAP Serialization from eating NewLines

Tags: c#, .net, soap, newline

I'm using the built-in SOAP support in .Net through a wrapper class generated by Visual Studio from a WSDL.
Now, when I call one one of the methods on the wrapper and pass an object that contains a string with CRLF (`\r\n`), only the LF (`\n`) will end up on the server. The same happens vice-versa. When the server sends a string containing CRLF, the wrapper will only spit out the LF.

I know this is a problem that can usually be avoided by supplying an own `XmlWriter` to the `XmlSerializer`, but I can't find a place where I could specify anything like that in the provided framework.

I almost want to go with the RegEx solution provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115459/xml-deserialization-standardising-line-endings-how-to-stop-it-net), but I have a hard time believing that there is nothing in place to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness sake, I didn't find a solution that provided what I was looking for. So the best solution for my case was going with the solution proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115473/259953).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340180/how-to-keep-xmlserializer-from-killing-newlines-in-strings)

```
    XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    ws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer( typeof( Abc ) );
    using (XmlWriter wr = XmlWriter.Create( "abc.xml", ws ))
    {
        ser.Serialize( wr, s );
    }
```

Comment: I'm aware of that solution for generic XML serialization. But in this case I am not the one doing the serialization. It happens inside the .Net Framework. So I don't see a place where I could supply custom XmlWriterSettings.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) to escape the carriage returns in the stream headed to the service ([SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapmessagestage.aspx)).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434975/c-sharp-extending-soapextension) points to a good resource explaining [how to implement one on v1.1](http://hyperthink.net/blog/inside-of-chainstream/) of the SOAP stuff; other examples are those which override [ProcessMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.processmessage.aspx) to [remove invalid XML characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082174/423430) or [log the entire SOAP conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/300821/423430). (Configuration involves a [SoapExtensionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextensionattribute.aspx) associating the extension with the web reference, typically setup in the web.config.)